# Save .CSS changes to a website on the client side

Tags: css, web

I have made some changes of the .CSS for a website, is it possible for me to save those changes, so that when I start the website the next time, it is kept? I do understand that I can't change the server code. I am asking if I am able to change this on the client side.

I have access to the following browsers:

- Internet Explorer 10
- Firefox
- Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without an extension, I use https://userstyles.org/ and their extension to modify css.  Plus there are free styles you can use.

However, you must modify via external css format.

Note: this is not compatible with IE, and I know it works with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped! :)